# can NOT store non-string Object when using StringRedisSerializer for HashValueSerializer

Tags: redis, jedis, spring-data-redis

I faced the ClassCastException exception when using the StringRedisSerializer  to store hash value. if if remove the non-string field 'age', then it can be stored into redis.

```
    Demo demo = new Demo();
    demo.setName("DemoCache_jsonSerializer");
    // non-string field
    demo.setAge(111);



    // set stringSerializer
    redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    //exception here: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    redisTemplate.opsForHash().putAll("testKey",
            mapper.toHash(demo));
```

I know if I change to jsonserializer it will work, but my question is
how to keep it work with the StringRedisSerializer ,and able to store object that has non-string fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `StringRedisSerializer` you can only convert `String` to `byte[]` and `byte[]` to `String`.
To keep it working with `StringRedisSerializer` better convert all the object to `String` maybe override `toString()`. But I guess this might be a bad design.

Have a look at the below links : [Source Code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/serializer/StringRedisSerializer.java) and [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:serializer) you might find something helpful.

Comment: @MunimMunna, I somehow missed this. Thanks for pointing out. Will be careful next time.

Answer (score 1):

```
   @Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
    final RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    template.setValueSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Object.class));
    template.afterPropertiesSet();
    return template; }
```